# Where do I put a dyndns script for IPv6?

Tags: networking, scripts, 14.10, ipv6, dyndns

I am using:

```
/sbin/ip -6 addr|grep -v temporary|grep 'scope global'|grep -oE '([0-9a-f]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}'
```

to grep my global, non-temporary IPv6 address, that is advertised by my router using NDP.

Now, I would like to report this address to a DynDNS service. Where would I put this script to be automatically executed on the change of the adress?

I think `/etc/network/if-up.d` is a wrong place since, as far as I understand, NDS might advertise a new address without the interface going down and up. Is there another script hook?

Comment: For now, I added a check if anything changed and am calling a cronjob once a minute ..

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from OPs comment:

> For now, I added a check if anything changed and am calling a cronjob
>   once a minute.